# Java - Server that services each client in a seperate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, client

I am trying to setup my MessageServer class so that it services each client in a separate request (you'll see below that it's pretty linear right now)

How should I go about it?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MessageServer {

public static final int PORT = 6100;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Socket client = null;
    ServerSocket sock = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        sock = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        // now listen for connections
        while (true) {
            client = sock.accept();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            Message message = new MessageImpl(reader.readLine());

            // set the appropriate character counts
            message.setCounts();

            // now serialize the object and write it to the socket
            ObjectOutputStream soos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            soos.writeObject(message);
            System.out.println("wrote message to the socket");

            client.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: i've been searching through my operating systems textbook trying to find a good read but not much is there :/

Comment: What part is taking too much time?  Have you tested?  How much speed do you need to gain under what load?  Premature optimization is the root of all evil, be sure you know what you are trying to do before undertaking this.  (For instance, in many cases threading may slow you down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your question doesn't make much sense.

If we are using the term "request" in the normal way, a client sends a request to the server and the server processes each request.  It simply makes no sense for a server to not service the requests separately (in some sense).

Perhaps you are asking something different.  (Do you mean, "service each client request in a separate thread"?)  Whatever you mean, please review your terminology.

---

Given that you are talking about executing requests in different threads, then using the `ExecutorService` API is a good choice.  Use an implementation class that allows you to put an upper bound on the number of worker threads.  If you don't, you open yourself up for problems where overload results in the allocation of large numbers of threads, which only makes the server slower.  (Besides, creating new threads is not cheap.  It pays to recycle them.)

You should also *consider* configuring your executor so that it doesn't have a request queue.  You want the executor service to block the thread that is trying to submit the job if there isn't a worker available.  Let the operating system queue incoming connections / requests at the `ServerSocket` level.  If you queue requests internally, you can run into the situation where you are wasting time by processing requests that the client-side has already timed out / abandoned.

Comment: that is what I meant yes; looking things over..would I perhaps use Executor interface?

Comment: i'm perusing Operating System Concepts with Java, 8th edition..wouldn't that have it?

Comment: That would work.  Indeed it is better than the naive "create a new thread for each request" approach.  Use an executor implementation that allows you to put a bound on the number of worker threads.

Comment: It probably would / should.  You were probably bitten by using the wrong terminology.